# Scala groupBy for a list

Tags: scala, list

I'd like to create a map on which the key is the string and the value is the number of how many times the string appears on the list. I tried the `groupBy` method, but have been unsuccessful with that.

Comment: Could you show your Map ? And what is your desired output?

Comment: My list is [abc,abc,cbe,cab]                                                                                                                                                                                                I've tried this, but it doesnt work.                                                           
 val c = b.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)                                                                I'd like the Map to look like this Map(abc->2, cbe->1, cab->1)

Comment: Show your Map.. Content of "b"

Comment: Can you provide your Map and desired Output as @Mahesh Chand Kanpal asked?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Required Answer

```
scala> val l = List("abc","abc","cbe","cab")
l: List[String] = List(abc, abc, cbe, cab)

scala> l.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size) 
res91: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(cab -> 1, abc -> 2, cbe -> 1)
```

Comment: [identity function in Predef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Predef$.html)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a *list* as

```
scala> val list = List("abc", "abc", "bc", "b", "abc")
list: List[String] = List(abc, abc, bc, b, abc)
```

You can write a *function*

```
scala> def generateMap(list: List[String], map:Map[String, Int]) : Map[String, Int] = list match {
     |       case x :: y => if(map.keySet.contains(x)) generateMap(y, map ++ Map(x -> (map(x)+1))) else generateMap(y, map ++ Map(x -> 1))
     |       case Nil => map
     |     }
generateMap: (list: List[String], map: Map[String,Int])Map[String,Int]
```

Then call the *function* as

```
scala> generateMap(list, Map.empty)
res1: Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 3, bc -> 1, b -> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```scala
scala> val l = List("abc","abc","cbe","cab")
val l: List[String] = List(abc, abc, cbe, cab)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
scala> l.groupBy(identity).map(x => (x._1, x._2.length))
val res1: Map[String, Int] = HashMap(cbe -> 1, abc -> 2, cab -> 1)
```