# How to get Map with matching values

Tags: scala

I have a file with values like this :

```
 user id | item id | rating | timestamp
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
6   86  3   883603013
62  257 2   879372434
200 222 5   876042340
210 40  3   891035994
224 29  3   888104457
303 785 3   879485318
122 387 5   879270459
194 274 2   879539794
......
```

I want to find all values where item id = "560"

and make Map from rating values(1-5) like this {1->6,2-5,3-10,4-6,5-14}

```
object Parse {

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //вытаскиваем данные с u.data
    var a: List[(String, String, String, String)] = List()
    for (line <- io.Source.fromFile("F:\\big data\\u.data").getLines) {
      val newLine = line.replace("\t", ",")
      if (newLine.split(",").length < 4) {
        break
      } else {
        val asd = newLine.split(",")
        val userId = asd(0)
        val itemId = asd(1)
        val rating = asd(2)
        val timestamp = asd(3)
        a = a :+ ((userId, itemId, rating, timestamp))
      }
      a = a.filter(_._2.equals("590")) <- filter list of tuples correctly
      val empty: List[String] = a.map(_._2) <- have tyed to get list of all rating, but it does not work

    
    }
}
```

How can I create a map of rating?
here as I can see we can generate a map of matching values
[Scala groupBy for a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327360/scala-groupby-for-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a `Map` of `rating`->`count` for a given "item id", this should do it.

```
util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("../junk.txt")) { file =>
  val rec = raw"\d+\s+590\s+(\d+)\s+\d+".r  //only this item id
  file.getLines()
      .collect { case rec(rating) => rating }
      .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
        case (m, r) => m + (r -> (m.getOrElse(r, 0) + 1))
      }
}.getOrElse(Map.empty[String,Int])
```

Note that `fromFile()` is automatically closed at the end of the `Using` block.

Comment: I would use `m.updatedWith(key = r) { case Some(x) => Some(x + 1); case None => Some(0) }`

Answer (score 0):

I think using `for-loop` is not the better decision. Please, look at your problem from the data-stream problem not array. `scala.io.Source.fromFile("F:\\big data\\u.data").getLines()` returns to you `Iterator[String]` of your lines. It is more suitable to use it as data stream not as array of data. And in your conditions is better just use combination of `map`, `filter`, `collect` and `groupBy` functions to get grouped rows by `rank`.

Full correct code:

```
val sourceFile = scala.io.Source.fromFile("F:\\big data\\u.data")
try {
  val linesOfArrays = sourceFile.getLines().map{
    line => line.split(",")
  }
  require(!linesOfArrays.exists(_.length < 4)) // your data schema validation
  val ratingCountsMap: Map[String, Int] = linesOfArrays.collect{
    case rowValuesArray if rowValuesArray(1) == "590" =>
      // in this line you will get rating and 1 for his counting
      rowValuesArray(2) -> 1
  }.toSeq
    .groupBy{ case (rating, _) => rating }
    .mapValues{ groupWithSameRating => groupWithSameRating.length }
} finally sourceFile.close()
```

And don't forget to *release* resource (in your case this is file) using `close` method in `finally` section or use **scala-arm** library (more about resources [here](https://blog.softwaremill.com/a-short-story-about-resource-handling-61b8405c352d))